# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api-dotnet-client

I am strugling for days with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker. It hangs adter windows update on 14'th July 2020, before that it worked perfect. Our IIS v.10 runs on Windows 10. We located that this function generates the hang out:

```
private async Task<UserCredential> GoogleAuthorize()
        {
            UserCredential userCredential = null;

            using (var stream = new FileStream($@"{_configuration["Documents:Root"]}client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                ClientSecrets secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;

                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                IEnumerable<string> scopes = new List<string>
                {
                    GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,
                    GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom,
                    GmailService.Scope.GmailModify
                };

                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

                FileDataStore file = new FileDataStore(@$"C:\Gmail\", true);

                userCredential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes, "username", ct, file);
            }

            return userCredential;
        }
```

Also tried like this:

```
private async Task<UserCredential> GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow()
{
            ClientSecrets secrets = null;
            UserCredential credentials = null;

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream($@"{_configuration["Documents:Root"]}client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;

            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initailizer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = secrets
            };

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

            IEnumerable<string> scopes = new List<string>
            {
                GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,
                GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom,
                GmailService.Scope.GmailModify
            };

            FileDataStore file = new FileDataStore(@$"C:\Gmail\", true);

            credentials = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(initailizer, scopes, "username", ct);

        }

        return await Task.FromResult(credentials);
}
```

Also we got some logs:
*Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile' is denied.*

*The service gmail has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential*

These functions works on local machine, but hangs on the server.

Comment: We found out, that the problem is in IIS configuration, because if we run the service form console app, it works on the server. We think that IIS has some permission settings changed.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is designed for use with installed applications.  It will open the login and consent screen on the machine that it is running on.  This will work fine on your machine in development but in the case of something hosted via IIS this will not work as its going to try and open the browser window on the server and not on the users machine.

for asp .net core you need to be adding the following to dependency injection

```
 .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            IConfigurationSection googleAuthSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
            options.ClientId = googleAuthSection["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = googleAuthSection["ClientSecret"];
            options.Scope.Add(Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
        });
```

I have a related question here [Connect to Google api via asp .net core causes endless authorization loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62791294/1841839)